# Sorting Datatable according to number not alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a datatable dt1:

```
Name Amount
----  -----
A     10
B     15
C     5
D     22
E     16
F     30
G     31
```

In c# I want to sort the data based on Low to High or Log to High depending on user select in the drop down box. I am using this function but it always sort alphabetically like 10,15,16,22,30,31,5. Anyone can please tell me what should I use to sort data.

```
protected void ddlHotelAPISearchBoxSorting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2 = dt1;

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);

        if (ddlHotelAPISearchBoxSorting.SelectedValue == "Low_Price_First")
        {
            //dt2.DefaultView.Sort = "CalculatedPrice ASC";
            dv.Sort = "CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol ASC";
        }
        else if (ddlHotelAPISearchBoxSorting.SelectedValue == "High_Price_First")
        {
            dv.Sort = "CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol DESC";
        }
        else if (ddlHotelAPISearchBoxSorting.SelectedValue == "Best_Match")
        {
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Is your `CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol` column being returned as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Custom Comparer` for your DataView. By default `sort of DataView compare strings` and for strings `16` comes before `5`.

This is how you can sort by `int` value of `CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol` in an ascending manner:

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

// Create temporary list to sort rows by int value.
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   rows.Add(row);    
}

// Sort list in ascending order
rows.Sort(delegate(DataRow row1, DataRow row2)
     {
         return ((int)row1["CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol"])
                  .CompareTo(((int)row2["CalculatedPriceWithNoSymbol"]));
     });

// Add sorted rows back to datatable.
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    dt2.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}

DataList1.DataSource = dt2;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

`dv.Sort` is a string that contains the column name followed by "ASC" (ascending) or "DESC" (descending). If `"Amount"` in your example is the column name by which you want to sort your data, you may try this`dv.Sort = "Amount ASC"`

Comment: I guess that's just a typo. Even then your answer won't work in case Amount is of string datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If you're `Amount` column is a string, then it collates, oddly enough, as a string. Consider converting it to `decimal` or `int`: if you do so, it will collate as you might expect it to.