# Sorting DataTable column is not working in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have `Form1` which has `button`, `Datagridview` and `flowLayoutPanel`. I have large address table in SQL (400,000 records) I am trying to import house numbers based on a specific given Postcode and then assign those numbers to button text as shown below:

```
     SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
     SqlCommand MySQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
     DataTable Data_Table1 = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter SQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();


  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string PostCode = "L8 8HN";

        Data_Table1.Rows.Clear();
        Data_Table1.Columns.Clear();  
        MyConnection.Open();          
        MySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PC where Postcode= '" + PostCode + "'";

        MySQLCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = MySQLCommand;
        SQLDataAdapter.Fill(Data_Table1);
        MySQLCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        SQLDataAdapter.Dispose();
        MyConnection.Close();


        // Sort the "Building Number" column. 
        DataTable dt2 = Data_Table1.Clone();
        dt2.Columns["Building Number"].DataType =    Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        foreach (DataRow dr in Data_Table1.Rows)
        {
            dt2.ImportRow(dr);
        }
        dt2.AcceptChanges();
        DataView dv = dt2.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Building Number ASC";


        //Create buttons and make Building Number as text.
       int RowIndex = dt2.Rows.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = dt2.Rows[i]["Building Number"].ToString();
            btn.Width = 50;
            btn.Height = 50;        
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        // check if the column "Building Number" is sorted or not.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;

}
```

When I click on `button1`, the SQL query brings all the Building Numbers based on a given Postcode, then sort the Building Numbers and after that create new buttons and make their text based on Building Numbers and at same time show the `dt2` in `datagridview`.

- The issue:

[image: screen shot]

As shown in the screen shot, the column "Building Number" in `datagridview` is sorted as I wanted but when I loop throw `dt2` and assign `buttons` text from `dt2` then in this case the `buttons` are not sorted in the correct way. 
The buttons should be sorted in the right way as in the `datagridview`

Note that the column "Building Number" in SQL table is type of string. Also I am using `datagridview` just to see if the column is sorted or not.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574853/sorting-the-datatable-is-not-working) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901590/sorting-datatable-according-to-number-not-alphabetically) but none of them helped me.

Please if anyone knows how can I get those buttons sorted in the correct way starting from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...

Thank you

Comment: are you creating buttons dynamically?

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15. yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an ordered `DataView`, but in the loop where buttons are being created, you are using `dt2` which is unordered. You should change that loop to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = dv[i]["Building Number"].ToString();
    btn.Width = 50;
    btn.Height = 50;        
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

As a better alternative, instead of all the steps you go through to order your data, why don't you get it already ordered in your sql query?

```
MySQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PC where Postcode= '" + PostCode + "' order by Building Number";
```

I also recommend you to use parametrized queries instead of concatenating strings to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: One up for Prepared Statements!

Comment: That's the ultimate solution with a little touch of magic. thank you